# How to install zipped eclipse plugin from local artifactory which has artifact.jar, content.jar and plugin folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, tycho, p2, eclipse-neon

I am trying to install a **zipped update site plugin** which I deployed it to my local artifactory using the below pom entry, **the packaging structure of this pom is eclipse-repository**

[image: pom for deploying]

It got successfully deployed in the below format:

[image: Structure of deployed update site]

**Notice that in the above image the zip has content.jar and artifact.jar which is necessary as referred to many solutions to install it from a zip. Also, I am using the p2 repository structure of neon2.**

But when I am trying to install it into my RCP application, it is giving me the below given error

[image: Error that I am getting while installing this plugin]

One observation that I had was, when I place the Update Site plugin in **unzipped format** in my local artifactory, then it **successfully gets installed** in my RCP application.

Can someone please help me out **how to install it from a zipped update site where it has the content.jar, artifact.jar and plugin jar**?
If not could you please help me with the deployment process using the structure of p2 repository and not deploy it in zipped format.

Comment: You should just use the 'Archive' option on the Add Repository dialog for a zip.

Comment: Hi @greg-449, I have used the 'Archive' option on the add repository dialog for zip. But I am facing the issue as mentioned in picture#3 that no software site found. Is there something that I am missing out?

Comment: The path for an archive would start with `jar` and end with `zip!/` - for example `jar:file:/Users/greg/Downloads/org.eclipse.cvs.source-4.17RC2.zip!/` is a path for the Eclipse CVS zipped repo which works for me

Comment: @greg-449, Thank you for your help. I was missing out on jar: and !/ after I had copy pasted the URL in the add repository archive. In case of local, it automatically appends jar: and !/. Whereas, in case of Web URL, I had to manually enter it.